# how to make a resizable crop rectangle to crop image in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, resize, crop

We are trying to make a drawing application, for that we require code to work with images (cropping,resizing,rotating,merging etc. the works) problem is we are novices(less than five months in iOS) so we require some things along the lines of a tutorial as well as enable us build an application. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

For cropping, you could follow the source code in my library. It will show you how to make a freehand crop tool and apply the cropping methods in core graphics.

https://github.com/nicholjs/BFCropInterface